Why is req.body undefined in Multer's diskStorage destination function?
I'm using Multer to handle file uploads in my Express.js application. I'm trying to access the req.body values in the destination function of Multer's diskStorage option, but it's returning undefined.how do i pass name from /registerartist to req.body of multer desination
Here's my code:
import express from 'express';
import {json} from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {mongoose} from 'mongoose'; 
import UserModel from './src/Models/usermodel.js';
import TrackModel from './src/Models/trackmodel.js';
import cors from 'cors';
import multer from 'multer';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
import SingerSchema from './src/Models/singermodel.js';
import Artist from './src/Models/artistmodel.js';


dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const app = express();
app.use(json());
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



// Define __dirname for path resolution
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

// Multer Storage Configuration
const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const { name } = req.body; 
        const folderPath = `./uploads/artists/${name}`;
        console.log(folderPath)
        if (!fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
          fs.mkdirSync(folderPath, { recursive: true });
        }
        cb(null, folderPath);
      },
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
      }
    })
  });
//connect to Database

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Anitify")
.then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to Mongodb")
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log("Error connecting to mongodb",err);
})




app.post('/registerartist', upload.single('image'),  (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, genre } = req.body;

  
    console.log("image is",req.file.image.originalname);
   
    console.log("bodyis",req.body.name);
  
   Artist.findOne({email:email})
   .then(result=>{
        if(!result){
            Artist.create(req.body);
        }else{
            console.log("already exists");
        }
   })
   .then(user=>res.json(user))
   .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.json(err)
   })
  });
  




The README of multer says Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server. so I guess it must have something to do with how the data is transmitted to the server.

Please see below the quote from Multer help. This is the same commented by @Greensaiko. A code example has been enclosed below to demo the same. It has been implemented to show when text field is added to the form object prior to file object, the text object has become accessible in the function for destination. However the when the order of objects added has been reversed, then text object becomes inaccessible. The server output shows the respective messages.

... Each function gets passed both the request (req) and some
information about the file (file) to aid with the decision.
Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends
on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.
...

server.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      let { name } = req.body;
      if (name) {
        console.log(`Text field received when url is ${req.url}`);
      } else {
        name = 'notavailable';
        console.log(`Text field not received when url is ${req.url}`);
      }
      const folderPath = `./uploads/artists/${name}`;
      //console.log(folderPath);
      if (!fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(folderPath, { recursive: true });
      }
      cb(null, folderPath);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
    },
  }),
});

app.post('/textandfile', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('done');
});

app.post('/fileandtext', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('done');
});

let body = new FormData();
body.set('name', 'somename'); // some text input
body.set('image', new Blob(['some image'])); // some blob/file content

fetch('http://localhost:3000/textandfile', {
  method: 'POST',
  body,
});

body = new FormData();
body.set('image', new Blob(['some image'])); // some blob/file content
body.set('name', 'somename'); // some text input

fetch('http://localhost:3000/fileandtext', {
  method: 'POST',
  body,
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

Test run & results:
node server.js
Text field received when url is /textandfile
Text field not received when url is /fileandtext

Citations:
Sending form data using fetch in Node.js
